# How to create an array of strucs in nasm?

Tags: nasm, ld

### Context

I am creating a simple CLI parser for a project with nasm, using nasm strucs to define the amount of arguments, callback and subcommand name. It works perfectly except when I define more than one element with that struct.

### Project

*argparser.inc*

```
struc command 
  .arg_count:   resd    1
  .name:        resq    1
  .fn:          resq    1
endstruc
```

*arun.asm*

```
%include "argparser.inc"
...
section .data
  commands_struct:
    istruc command
      at command.arg_count, dd  2
      at command.name,      dq  command_names.create
      at command.fn,        dq  create
    iend
```

### Error

This works as expected. But as explained before if I add another one as seen below:

*arun.asm*

```
%include "argparser.inc"
...
section .data
  commands_struct:
    istruc command
      at command.arg_count, dd  2
      at command.name,      dq  command_names.create
      at command.fn,        dq  create
    iend

    istruct command
      at command.arg_count, dd  1
      at command.name,      dq  command_names.start
      at command.fn,        dq  start
    iend
```

The error is the following (refering to the second `istruct` at line 31 until `iend` at line 35):

```
arun.asm:31: error: parser: instruction expected
arun.asm:32: error: `%$strucname': context stack is empty
arun.asm:32: error: `%$strucstart': context stack is empty
arun.asm:32: error: `%$strucname': context stack is empty
arun.asm:32: error: `%$strucstart': context stack is empty
arun.asm:32: error: expression syntax error
arun.asm:33: error: `%$strucname': context stack is empty
arun.asm:33: error: `%$strucstart': context stack is empty
arun.asm:33: error: `%$strucname': context stack is empty
arun.asm:33: error: `%$strucstart': context stack is empty
arun.asm:33: error: expression syntax error
arun.asm:34: error: `%$strucname': context stack is empty
arun.asm:34: error: `%$strucstart': context stack is empty
arun.asm:34: error: `%$strucname': context stack is empty
arun.asm:34: error: `%$strucstart': context stack is empty
arun.asm:34: error: expression syntax error
arun.asm:35: error: `%$strucname_size': context stack is empty
arun.asm:35: error: `%$strucstart': context stack is empty
arun.asm:35: error: `%$strucname_size': context stack is empty
arun.asm:35: error: `%$strucstart': context stack is empty
arun.asm:35: error: expression syntax error
arun.asm:35: error: `%pop': context stack is empty
```

Comment: I fixed the `istruct` typo (should not have a trailing T) and added labels you omitted and it works fine, at least on "NASM version 2.17rc0 compiled on May 1 2023". Test file at https://pushbx.org/ecm/test/20230626/test.asm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by [@ecm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/738287/ecm) it is fine to have multiple strucs it was just a typo in the keyword used. The fixed code would be:

*arun.asm*

```
%include "argparser.inc"
...
section .data
  commands_struct:
    istruc command
      at command.arg_count, dd  2
      at command.name,      dq  command_names.create
      at command.fn,        dq  create
    iend

    istruc command
      at command.arg_count, dd  1
      at command.name,      dq  command_names.start
      at command.fn,        dq  start
    iend
```